# Questions about mixed precision in Tensorflow2.1

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, precision, tensorflow2.x

I've read this [official document](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/mixed_precision#setting_the_dtype_policy) about mixed precision in tensorflow 2.1 and get several questions about mixed-precision:

1. Why do we cast the outputs to `float32` even when we use `mixed_float16`, which actually output `float16` in the intermediate layers? The [official document](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/mixed_precision#building_the_model) says outputs of `float16` are not always numerically stable, but what does that mean? Why would simply casting to `float32` improve numeric stability?
2. [The document](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/mixed_precision#loss_scaling) recommends using loss scaling to avoid underflow. However, as the network weights, loss, and gradients are all `float32`, how would such underflow happen?